Add a keyboard shortcut for adding a post to saves
I use the saves feature a lot, and I also use my keyboard a lot. It would be nice to have a keyboard shortcut for saving a post.
I dunno. How about v,s (as in "vote -> save").

I was thinking about this while reading the "mouse" version you posted, but then how to select the answer(s) vs. question you want to save via keyboard?  I mean, I could probably do a userscript for this, but it would require some way to select the target.

I'd add in a third-option:  API access to saves.  We used to have API access to "Favorites", but it never was updated for "Saves".

@NotTheDr01ds same way as you select a post for flagging, commenting, voting. j,k,u. API access is a nice idea. I'd encourage a new feature-request post for that. honestly, for our use-case, some sort of scripting/automation is best.

Huh - TIL keyboard shortcuts are an opt-in feature on SE ... :-P - Now that's going to save me a boatload of time.  Thanks!
